# $(2x^2+1)(2y^2+1)=4z^2+1$ has no positive integer solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Equation

$$(2x^2+1)(2y^2+1)=4z^2+1$$

has no solutions in the positive integers. Its true?

Comment: There are no solutions according to Theorem 6 in Kashihara: Explicit complete solution in integers of a class of equations $(ax^2-b)(ay^2-b)=z^2-c$, Manuscripta Math. 80 (1993), 373-392.

Comment: @GHfromMO Hey why didn't you type that as answer? My request would be to type your comment as an answer so that this question is removed from the unanswered list :)

Comment: I don't understand you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By popular demand, I turn my comment to an answer:

There are no solutions according to Theorem 6 in Kashihara: Explicit complete solution in integers of a class of equations $(ax^2−b)(ay^2−b)=z^2−c$, Manuscripta Math. 80 (1993), 373-392.